# How update/refresh options dynamicaly datetimepicker

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, datetimepicker

Is there any way to update the option(s) of datetimepicker dynamicaly ?

In my case, on start, i setting my "busy dates" array in the option **disabledTimeIntervals ** of the plugin. It working fine but when I change my differents dates, I update the "busy dates" array and I try to set new option disabledTimeIntervals by passing the updated array each time I change the date like this :

```
$scope.options = {
                    locale: 'fr',
                    sideBySide: true,
                    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY à HH:mm',
                    useCurrent: false,
                    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
                    stepping: 15,
                    disabledTimeIntervals: $scope.getBusyDates(),
                    ignoreReadonly: true
                };

element.datetimepicker(eval($scope.options));
```

Unfortunatly that doesn't work and datetimepicker ignore my news settings ... How I can force datetimepicker to review the options when I want ? thank's

Answer (score 0):

Response : For set this new option I have to use the Option function : (http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#options)

So, the correct syntaxe response is :

```
element.data('DateTimePicker').options(eval(scope.options));
```